# Calculating value of a variable in combination?

Tags: combinations, binomial-theorem

Using the formula (bionomial theorem):

$${}_nC_r \cdot a^{n-r} \cdot b^{r}$$

i was trying to find out the term with the coefficient $400$ from $(2x + 5y)^5$? Then i came up with this equation which i have no idea to solve beside trying numbers between 1 and 5. Is there any other way?

$$2^{5-r} \cdot 5^{r} \cdot {}_5C_r = 400$$

can we find the value of r without brute forcing?

Comment: Are you sure $40$ not $400$? There are no (integer) solutions for the case $=40$ @ASB

Comment: Yes, it is 400. Sorry I missed typed the question. I have now edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac{2^5}{2^r} \cdot 5^r \cdot \binom 5r = 400$

$\frac{32}{2^r} \cdot 5^r \cdot \binom 5r = 400$

$\frac{1}{2^r} \cdot 5^r \cdot \binom 5r = \frac{25}{2}$

$\frac{1}{2^r} \cdot 5^r \cdot \binom 5r = \frac{5 \cdot 5}{2}$

$\frac{1}{2^r} \cdot 5^r \cdot \binom 5r = \frac{5}{2} \cdot \binom 51$

On comparing both sides,

$2^r = 2^1$

$r = 1$

Comment: Thank you! 
i also  tried comparing but got stuck on $$2^{5-r} \cdot 5^{r} \cdot {}_5C_r = 2^{4} \cdot 5^{2} \cdot 1 $$ since the combination cannot be 1, i concluded comparing wouldn't work.

Comment: I think it didn't work because I didn't simplify both sides completely.

Comment: In your first comment compare $2^{5-r}$ with $2^r$

Comment: Comparing might not always work, take this question for example: 
$$2^{4-r} \cdot 3^{r} \cdot {}_4C_r = 216$$

The answer is 2, trying possible values for r (1 to 4)

Comment: You can get. But its much complex each time.

Comment: $\frac 1{2^r}.3^r.\binom 4r = \frac 14.3^2.\binom 42$. But I must say hit and trail is better option.

Comment: Hit and trial might seem an option here, but if you have looked at your explanations carefully, I think we have an algorithm. We put one term powered to r in the denominator and the others in the numerator. So in the first question the whole thing $$5^{r} \cdot {}_5C_r = 25$$ while $$2^{r} = 2$$. Applying this to the second question; $$2^{r} = 4$$ while the whole $$3^{r} \cdot {}_4C_r = 27$$ 
So every time we are supposed to get one term to the denominator side and make the same thing happen from the other side.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume there is an exact (positive integer) solution to:

$$2^{5-r} \cdot 5^{r} \cdot {5 \choose r} = 5^2(2^4)$$

Clearly then $0 \leq r \leq 5$.

Then

$$2^{5-r} \cdot 5^{r} \cdot (5)....(5-r+1)=r! (5^2(2^4))$$

If $r=5$ then exponent of $5$ on both sides do not match. So by the fundamental  theorem of arithmetic $r \neq 5$. Continuing from there, the exponent of $5$ must be $2$ on the left hand side, hence we must have:

$$5^{r+1}=5^2$$

By inspection $r=1$ and we check to see that this works.